# How to say "I accept" in Japanese

Tags: words, word-requests

I know that 断る means decline, but I couldn't find the meaning of accept.

I want to say something like "I accept your offer"

Comment: What did you find when you tried? Lots of entries in a Japanese-English dictionary will include some form of "accept."

Comment: Well, when I wrote it into Japandict, i found 合う、受付、常識 and whatnot and none of them were actually related to the original search

Comment: None??? I find that a bit hard to comprehend.  It seems that there are a few plausible ones depending on the context:  なっとくする, 受け入れる, 採用する.  Granted, from the first search　受け入れる might be harder to find.  But the others are there.  How deeply did you dig into the first list?

Comment: What kind of acceptance are we talking about here? When you say "I accept your offer", are you referring to an "offer" like a proposed salary increase, or like an object that someone is physically trying to give you? Because I think those will require different kinds of responses. One could also "accept" information, or even something like bad news, which I would say are also different senses that might require different translations.

Answer (score 1):

- 「承知（しょうち）しました」：respectful
- 「了解（りょうかい）しました」：polite
- 「わかりました」：normal
- 「いいよ」：very casual